# How do i write an automatic phone receiver?

Tags: java, android

i want to set a sms verification in my app.
i looked in some websites and understood that there is a way to get the user phone num without requesting it. i've found this code for doing it:

```
private void requestHint() {
    HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
            .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
            .build();

    PendingIntent intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
            apiClient, hintRequest);
    startIntentSenderForResult(intent.getIntentSender(),
            RESOLVE_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

i didnt understood what should be put in the "apiClient" variable

what should i enter in this variable?

tnx!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the apiclient for HintRequest like

```
apiClient  = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
    .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
    .build();
```